# WSO2 ESB: Aggregating JSON responses from multiple api calls

Tags: json, api, wso2, aggregate, esb

I am using WSO2 ESB mediators to try and to create an API which paginates a particular Rest API. I am using recursion with the sequence mediator to make calls to a dynamically changing endpoint until all data has been collected. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to aggregate all the responses into one JSON before sending.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the current code:

```
<api context="/axceleratePaginated" name="axceleratePaginated">
    <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" url-mapping="/courses">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="uri.var.resource" value="courses"/>
            <property name="uri.var.offset" value="0"/>
            <property name="uri.var.displayLength" value="99"/>
            <property name="JSONContinue" value="true"/>
            <sequence key="paginationSequence"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <!-- aggregate here? -->
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
...
<sequence name="paginationSequence" trace="enable">
    <header name="apitoken" scope="transport" value="***********"/>
    <header name="wstoken" scope="transport" value="************"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" trace="enable" uri-template="https://admin.axcelerate.com.au/api/{uri.var.resource}?displayLength={uri.var.displayLength}&amp;offset={uri.var.offset}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="JSONPayload"/>
    <filter regex="true" source="get-property('JSONContinue')">
        <then>
            <script language="js">
                <![CDATA[
                    java.lang.Thread.sleep(200);
                    var offset = parseInt(mc.getProperty('uri.var.offset'));
                    offset += 100;
                    var pl_string = mc.getProperty('JSONPayload');
                    var JSONPayloadLength = pl_string.length();
                    if (JSONPayloadLength === 3){
                        mc.setProperty('JSONContinue','false');
                    }
                    offset = offset.toString();
                    mc.setProperty('uri.var.offset',offset);
                ]]>
            </script>
            <sequence key="paginationSequence"/>
        </then>
    </filter>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Loopback mediator [1] to send  messages from the in flow (request path) to the out flow (response path).

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Loopback+Mediator

Comment: Could you please show me how the code should look with the Loopback mediator? I'm not sure how this would allow me to collect the multiple json response bodies and concatenate them into a single response